# Setting PHP path in Mac OS X Mountain Lion Server

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion, updates

I have upgraded PHP from 5.3.15 to 5.4.16 on My Mountain Lion Server. Following Steps from [this Link](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/upgrade-to-php-5-4-or-5-5-on-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/)

I also updated new PHP path to bash profile. Now I have two different PHP version displayed.

In terminal `which php` command points to upgraded php
`/usr/local/php/bin/php/`

`php -v` also points to upgraded version `5.4.16`.

But page created with `phpinfo()` and `phpmyadmin` still points to `PHP/5.3.15`

Is there any other files that needs to be reconfigured after PHP upgrade on a Mountain Lion Server?

I have followed the same installation in my local machine running Mac Mountain Lion. I had no issues with upgrade.

Comment: did you restart apache after your install?

Comment: Yep did both via terminal and inbuilt server GUI. dosent seem to have any effect. Also tried to restart browser.

Comment: well do a `find / -name libphp5.so` and see if you get more than 1

Comment: I got 5. `Applications/MAMP/php/php5.2.17/modules/libphp5.so`, `Applications/MAMP/php/php5.3.6/modules/libphp5.so`, `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp5.so`, `usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` -> Think this is picked up by `phpinfo()`, `usr/local/php5-5.4.16-20130615-025727/libphp5.so` -> This is picked up by `php -v`

Answer (score 5):

Came across this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22233581#22233581) under apple support.

Apple recommends not to upgrade inbuilt PHP, Since its used by other applications running inside server. PHP upgrade will be done along with Apple updates after apple test next version of PHP.

They do provide steps to update after recommending not to ,And to upgrade

`sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.orig`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

and update apache conf file with

`LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so`